# Can a chameleon qualify for blighter?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, multi-classing, prestige-class, chameleon

An ex-druid 1 / chameleon (*Races of Destiny*) wants to take levels in blighter (*Complete Divine*). Can he?

Comment: Is there a *reason* the chameleon wants to take levels in blighter specifically, or is this more of a theoretical question because you're actually, like, wondering how the chameleon's divine focus works or something? (I ask because blighters tend not to live very long.)

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan: Yes, the player really likes blighter for role playing: 'kill an entire field' makes causing a famine to overthrow a king easier. Yes there are easier ways, but player wants it. Pointed out diminish plants and using summoned fire elemental too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A level 1 ex-druid with the prestige class chameleon (*Races of Destiny* 111-7) that once used the extraordinary ability aptitude focus to gain divine focus to cast druid spells and that has Wisdom 16 (if a 3rd-level chameleon) or Wisdom 13 (if a 4th-level chameleon) so that it can meet the blighter prerequisite of being able to cast 3rd-level druid spells could *possibly* take levels in blighter (*Complete Divine* 23-6).

The blighter's special requirement says, "The character must be an ex-druid previously capable of casting 3rd-level druid spells" (*CD* 23), and those statements aren't independent. Thus the DM may require the chameleon to be, instead of a 1st-level ex-druid, a *5th-level* ex-druid, the minimum druid level for casting 3rd-level druid spells.

Also, the prestige class chameleon on Class Features says, "You can’t use any abilities gained from your aptitude focus… to qualify for a… prestige class" (*Races of Destiny* 112). So the player must make the argument that—and here I suggest first buying pizza if not good booze—using the *absence* of something to meet the prestige class's requirement is *different* from using the thing *itself* to meet the prestige class's requirement. I can't imagine such an argument working in most circles *without* the booze; stay safe and good luck.

(When composing this answer initially, I—like, I'm sure, many others—overlooked that chameleon Class Features text; thanks to [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/88580/8610) for pointing it out.)

Comment: "Seriously, why would you want to play this?" - for those of us out of the loop, could you clarify what you mean by 'this'? Is 'this' a character that goes from druid to blighter?

Comment: @doppelgreener Really, just blighter. The blighter throws away levels in the game's most powerful class to (eventually) kill a 200-ft. *radius* of thriving plant life *per day* to cast a far weaker selection of spells. Blighters paint giant *Kill Me* signs on their backs by existing. But perhaps I shouldn't judge.

Comment: An advisory of "this might be a really terrible idea" when relevant is never totally uncalled for and will probably be appreciated by at least some readers. If it's concerning to you, I suggest mentioning why at the end.

Comment: @doppelgreener That's fair. I'll bounce it back to querent.

Comment: Aren't blighters one of the three classes on the accelerated spell level track though? I thought it was them, Ur-Priests, and Beholder Mages.

Comment: @fectin Blighters can, in fact, cast 9th-level spells by character level about 14, but, without somehow adding spells to the blighter's spell list, those spells are numerically limited, mostly pretty terrible, and at a caster level equal to blighter level. For a horrible example, the blighter gets [*create undead*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/createUndead.htm) as a 5th-level spell at about character level 10 but at caster level **5**. So unless the poor blighter , for example, takes *another* prestige class to increase his caster level, he'll never even be able to create a ghoul.

Comment: The contentious issue of losing prereqs doesn't apply here, since Blighter's prereq is merely "*previously* capable of casting 3rd-level druid spells". If divine focus counts at all, then having used it once ever is enough.

Answer (score 8):

**No.**

*Races of Destiny*, page 112:

> You can't use any abilities gained from your aptitude focus, ability boon, or mimic class feature abilities to qualify for a feat, prestige class, or other option.

Were it not for this frequently-overlooked bit of text, the other answers would be correct.  Alas...

Comment: I realize this question is rather old, but I stumbled upon it searching for another one, and clearly we can't let an incorrect answer stand.

Answer (score -2):

**Yes.** Any *race* or *class* that can meet the requirements<sup>1</sup> would work.

With Chameleon, specifically, you would require:

> **Divine Focus:** You gain the ability to prepare and cast divine spells, which may be chosen from the spell list of *any divine spell-casting class*.

And of course, have the Chameleon level required to cast 3<sup>rd</sup> level spells. Could the Chameleon cast 3<sup>rd</sup> level druid spells? Yes, they can.

---

<sup>1</sup>**Requirements**

- **Base Attack Bonus:** +4
- **Alignment:** Any nongood
- **Special:** The character must be an ex-druid previously capable of
  casting 3rd-level druid spells, Profession skill must be herbalist.

Comment: OP specified that he only ever had 1 level of druid, so the "3rd-level druid spells" part of the third requirement isn't obviously met. If it's met in a non-obvious way, please call that out. Otherwise, the answer should be "no".

Comment: @MatthewNajmon Chameleons can cast divine spells of any list.

Comment: Would a Clr5/exDrd1 qualify, then, since the Cleric also has some lvl3 spells that are also on the druid list? By RAW, it is entirely unclear that being drawn from the druid's list automatically makes those spells count as "druid spells" for purposes of the prerequisite.

Comment: @MatthewNajmon No, because Cleric's don't have access to the Druid Spell List, regardless if they share spells.