# Must a Wizard specialize in Abjuration in order to qualify for Incantatrix?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

[This](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/19558/30299) (excellent!) answer mentions that a Wizard must specialize in Abjuration in order to qualify for Incantatrix.  I can't find this rule - as far as I can tell, the only restriction is that the Wizard cannot have Abjuration as a banned school.

*From Player's Guide to Faerûn, p. 61:*

> **Special:** The candidate cannot have abjuration as a prohibited school.

However, KRyan's expertise on the subject, plus 3.5's tendency to put [important rules in weird places](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/88580/30299), leads me to wonder if this might be a rule I missed somehow.

So, does a Wizard who wants to be an Incantatrix have to specialize in Abjuration?

Comment: This probably should have just been a comment on the answer...

Comment: Haha, I asked it in chat originally and was told to post it as a main site question.  Stack is hard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it doesn’t; I just misremembered that detail. (Note: I have since fixed it.)

Note that incantatrix appears in both *Magic of Faerûn* and *Player’s Guide to Faerûn*—with fairly significant changes between printings—and it doesn’t require that you be an abjurer in either.

Comment: Per the *Magic Of Faerûn* version: "In effect, the incantatrix is a specialist in the school of abjuration (gaining all the benefits of specializing in a school), and the incantatrix must choose an additional school or schools..." This is gained as a feature, not a prerequisite though. The *Player’s Guide to Faerûn* version may not have abjuration banned, and must ban an additional school at first level. So, both versions are very closely tied to abjuration specialization, even though it's not prerequisite.